# Euler's method (ODE) code implementation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to write a program in Python to solve a simple initial value problem with Euler's Method for ODEs. Programming is not my forte at all, so I am having trouble with implementation. I would like a push in the right direction, but I **don't** want someone to just give me working code. Thanks.

The problem is as follows: Given the Initial Value Problem,

$y' = y, $

$y(0) = 1$.

We want to use Euler's Method to approximate $y(4)$. Here is my attempt:

```
  ## This code is to implement Euler's Method for solving a simple ODE.
## Consider the I.V.P:  y' = y, y_0 = 1 ;
## We wish to use the method to approximate y(4):
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define the function
def f(t,y):
    return y

t_init = 0
t_end = 4
y_init = 1

# step size h, and number of steps n
h = 1
n = 4

# for graph
t = np.arange(t_init, t_end)

# initial condition in y
y = np.zeros(h)
y[0] = y_init

for i in xrange(1, n):
   t[i] = t_init + i * h
   y[i] = y[i-1] + h * f(t,y)

plt.plot(t, y)
plt.show()
```

In particular, I would like to know (1) Do I need to include the time step $t_n = t_0 + n h$ and $t_{n+1} = t_n + h$ inside my for loop? (2) What is the best way to define the function $f$ [for the general IVP, $y' = f(t, y(t))$]?

Lastly, is there anything that's just flat out wrong or unnecessary ? I would like for my program/code to be efficient as well. Again, thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Hi. This question would probably fit in better on the SE site for Computational Science, or perhaps the SE site for Code Reviews for the "Lastly" part. StackOverflow could also work. This SE is more for clean math questions, rather than implementation of computer programs doing numerics.

Comment: You should check that arange is doing the thing you want it to do (you should have the array [0,1,2,3,4] for your times). Your initial y vector should be np.zeros(n), not np.zeros(h). You could do the same with your t vector (filling it with zeros and then correcting as you loop through), or you can simply construct it in advance instead of reassigning it during the loop. Your call to f(t,y) should be f(t[i-1],y[i-1]).

Comment: Actually your initial y vector should be np.zeros(n+1); n is the number of times *after* the initial time.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ian, your comments really helped me make my code actually work. Really appreciate it!